# Define order of elements

Tags: scala

I would like to define an order between given elements: `El1 *isBefore* El2 *isBefore* El3`; to later use through a function like below.

```scala
def isBefore(a: T, b: T): Boolean = ???
```

Does it make any sense? And is it at least possible?

Comment: i dont understand the question. So isBefore is a method of a collection? could you provide additional context

Comment: Not all types have an order, thus no. But, what you can do is to write a function that only works if the type of the inputs has an **Order**, whenever you want to represent that kind of constraints, the best solution is a **typeclass**. - And in this case, that **typeclass** already exists on the _stdlib_, it is [`Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if `E11`, `E12`, etc., are supposed to be types (thus the leading capital letter) or values. The reference to "elements" leads me to think it's the latter.

You're using two different meanings for `isBefore`, both as statement as well as question. That's going to lead to confusion.

Here's my guess at what you might be trying to accomplish.

```
class Elem {
  private var next :Option[Elem] = None
  def comesBefore(after :Elem) :Elem = {next=Some(after); after}
  def isBefore(other :Elem) :Boolean = next.contains(other)
}

// create elements
val e23 = new Elem
val eBX = new Elem
val e$$ = new Elem

// set their order
eBX comesBefore e$$ comesBefore e23

// test their order
e23 isBefore e$$  //false
e$$ isBefore e23  //true
eBX isBefore e$$  //true
eBX isBefore e23  //false
```